# JavaScript time is an hour behind after ISO conversion

Tags: javascript, datetime, iso

I create a new Date in JavaScript, with the correct time, but after I use `toISOString()` to convert it, it's an hour behind. Why would that be?

https://jsfiddle.net/73nfyxeL/

```
var createdDateTime = new Date('2015-04-01 11:53:00');
var isoCreatedDateTime = "";

alert(createdDateTime);
isoCreatedDateTime = createdDateTime.toISOString().match(/(\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2})T(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/);
alert(isoCreatedDateTime[1] + ' ' + isoCreatedDateTime[2]);
createdDateTime.setMinutes(createdDateTime.getMinutes() + 1);
```

As far as I'm aware this should be immune to changes to the local time (eg. daylight savings), as I'm giving it a pre-set time, and not a timezone. What's going on?

Comment: `var createdDateTime = new Date('2015-04-01 11:53:00');` gives invalid date :)

Comment: It should be `var createdDateTime = new Date('2015-04-01T11:53:00');`

Comment: @mohamedrias That worked. I guess adding the T sets it to UTC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`toISOString` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) doesn't only format the date, first it is converted to UTC.

The difference between your local time zone and UTC is one hour.

Comment: This is correct, and be aware that UTC has no notion of Daylight Savings Time. So if the code worked last week and this week seems broken, guess what happened this past weekend? The UK switched from being UTC exactly to UTC+1 for Daylight Savings.